# Storage data is lost when closing an app or rebooting device

Tags: android, sqlite, storage, cordova, local-storage

Save data: `localstorage.setItem ('name', 'value');`
When forced to close the app or reboot the device, all of the storage data are lost.

Please help me to fix the problem.

Comment: which PhoneGap version are you using, and what Android SDK version are you targeting / have tested this one?

Comment: latest stable (0.9.3), SDK 2.1 || 2.2

Answer (score 1):

If you are saving to SharedPreferences, then you have to commit it to save permanently.

Comment: i use localstorage (html5 storage) - phonegap use localstorage is sqlite implementation